# Mulesoft best practices for API-led connectivity , is it okay to invoke System API directly from the client application(be it web/mobile)

Tags: api, anypoint-studio, mulesoft

The main reason for this question is to understand/reasons behind the best practices over the usage of system APIs. If the System API itself good enough to be serve the purpose of my client application, do we still need to write an experience API to invoke the system API indirectly, or break the rule, just invoke the system-API directly from the client application. As sometimes , it is overhead/numerous API calls over the network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

System API is to unlock or expose the system asset(back end data). Now, one could write the system API in such a way that it fetches the data from system database, does the required processing, for instance convert the table rows to JSON format and then does some enrichment & trimming of fields and expose it to the customer A. This is a course grained approach. Now, another customer B requires similar data but needs some fields that were already trimmed by you to serve Customer A who wanted only few fields of the many fields that you picked from System(database). You'll have to write a separate course grained API for Customer B. 
Also, in the future if the backend SYSTEM is replaced with a new SYSTEM, one would have to re-write/update both the API's for each customer A and customer B.

This course grained approach would solve your problem each time, but architecturally having a fine grained approach of breaking down a large service into multiple layers of experience, process and system API's would enable re-use, reduce work effort, increase time to market, lower total cost of ownership and allow applying the required separate policies(Security, sla's etc) for each of the clients through experience API layer. You can now better scale your integration landscape.

A fine grained approach increases usage of resources such as network, diskspace(more logging) etc but its a trade-off to all the many advantages you get. Again, the decision to go with either of the approaches should align with the current circumstances of your ecosystem, so it all depends.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Rohan and sorry for the delayed response.